# Consider adding '".indexOn": "mo"' at Users/users to your security and Firebase Database rules for better performance

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

here is my

Users
     users
       mo: value
       pa: value
       userid:value

and my database rules are

```
{
  "rules": {

    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,

}
}
```

So can someone please tell me what's causing this

> "Consider adding ".indexOn": "mo" at Users/users to your security and
>   Firebase Database rules for better performance"

Comment: I believe that's just a warning and not really an error. You can read about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data)

Comment: Something in your code is querying `/Users/users`. Firebase is telling you that this query is currently being performed in the app itself. Adding an index as described in the message will allow Firebase to perform the query on the server. To get better help, share the actual [code that triggers the message](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).